# What does Float.floatToRawIntBits(); return in java?

Tags: java, floating-point, binary

I am trying to get Java to return a binary representation of a float value. Let's say "0.125".

As far as I'm concerned 0.125 in binary32 equals:
00111110 00000000 00000000 00000000

This is also what I expect Java to return when running the following code:

```
int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(0.125f);
System.out.println(bits);
```

However this code returns this value: 1040187392

My two questions are:

- How do I get java to return the requested binary representation?
- What is the meaning of the number that it returned?

Comment: You used `floatToIntBits`, not `floatToRawIntBits()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need one more conversion:

```
int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(0.125f);
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bits));
```

Comment: So the value it returned was the decimal representation of 00111110 00000000 00000000 00000000?

Answer (score 2):

This method return a representation of the specified floating-point value, not the binary value.